# React router, redux, asynchronous API requests and a flash of old data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-router

Lets say I have the following code (as an example):

```
import React from 'react'

import { Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import { useEffect } from 'react'

import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

const Component1 = () => {
  const items = useSelector(state => state.app.items);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = makeUrl();

    dispatch(fetchItems(url));
  }, []);

  return (
    <p>
      Component1 renders!
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => {
          return (
          <li key={uuild()}>
            <Item1 {...item} />
          </li>);
        })}
      </ul>
    </p>
  )
}

const Component2 = () => {
  const items = useSelector(state => state.app.items);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = makeUrl();

    dispatch(fetchItems(url));
  }, []);

  return (
    <p>
      Component2 renders!
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => {
          return (
          <li key={uuild()}>
            <Item2 {...item} />
          </li>);
        })}
      </ul>
    </p>
  )
}

const MainComponent = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from="/" to="/component1"/>
        <Route exact path="/component1" component={Component1} />
        <Route exact path="/component2" component={Component2} />
      </Switch>
      <Link to="/component1">Component1</Link>
      <Link to="/component2">Component2</Link>
    </>
  )
}
```

There's two routes navigating to two different components each with its own distinct UI/layout, API request logic, etc. When I move to either of the routes, the corresponding component renders.

Everything works as intended but note that I make an API request after a component renders for the first time using `useEffect` with a special second parameter. So, when the url changes, the old component unmounts and the other one mounts in his place, resulting in a new API request. Inside each component I have a dependency on the state, namely the `items` property. The `fetchItems` sends an API requests and sets the new data when it is ready, so the component re-renders.

The problem is, until another portion of data is ready, my state contains some old, now irrelevant data from the last request. When the new component is shown, it will render this old data once, only then will it make a new request. This results in the new layout displaying the old data, which doesn't always make sense.

I could somewhat alleviate this issue by clearing all data before making a request, inside `fetchItems`. BUT, because of how react effects work, it will happen only AFTER the url has changed, so my component will render with the old data, only then will it render with empty data. If my layout is somewhat complex, the flash of the new UI displaying old data becomes noticeable. Is there a nice and painless way of dealing with it and making my component not re-render old data until new data becomes available, inside a **functional component**?

I know I could make two separate fields for each type of data in the state, but this wouldn't resolve the issue at all as then my component would render the corresponding data from the last request of its own.

Comment: You could simply initiate the render of each component as empty, e.g. `let content = []` , and when the fetch is complete update it with the content, e.g. you could add a new `const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)`. When your fetch completes you update `setLoading(false)` and then check for a condition `if (!loading) { content = <div>...</div>}` and then return the content.

Comment: But looking at my example code, from the viewpoint of a component, how do I determine whether the data is ready? All the actual request logic happens inside `fetchItems`, which is hidden behind a redux thunk. A component knows only about `items` and there is no way to know if `items` is fresh inside a component. When/how do I call `setIsLoading`?

Comment: You mean that the `fetchItems` is a redux action function. In that case in your redux store add a new key `loading: true`, before running the axios call in the `fetchItems` run another action to update the redux state loading to true and after the fetch completes update redux state loading to false. Now in your component import loading from the redux store: `const loading = useSelector(state => state.loading);` and check against it's value.  iI loading is true clear the content (or even better replace it with a spinner).

Comment: But again, when a new component should render after the url has just changed, because `fetchItems` is inside an effect (which executes after each render), if there was another API request before, `isLoading` will be `false` and therefore this newly displayed component will render the old data.

Comment: Exactly, so when the component loads you dispatch an action to the redux store to set loading to `true` and that will instantly clean the content.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the component loads"?

Comment: I prepared a codesandbox for you with everything you need: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-tu-z408u